# Adding a path to pandas to_csv function

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

I have a small chunk of code using Pandas that reads an incoming CSV, performs some simple computations, adds a column, and then turns the dataframe into a CSV using to_csv.

I was running it all in a Jupyter notebook and it worked great, the output csv file would be there right in the directory when I ran it. I have now changed my code to be run from the command line, and when I run it, I don't see the output CSV files anywhere. The way that I did this was saving the file as a .py, saving it into a folder right on my desktop, and putting the incoming csv in the same folder.

From similar questions on stackoverflow I am gathering that right before I use to_csv at the end of my code I might need to add the path into that line as a variable, such as this.

```
path = 'C:\Users\ab\Desktop\conversion'

final2.to_csv(path, 'Combined Book.csv', index=False)
```

However after adding this, I am still not seeing this output CSV file in the directory anywhere after running my pretty simple .py code from the command line.

Does anyone have any guidance? Let me know what other information I could add for clarity. I don't think sample code of the pandas computations is necessary, it is as simple as adding a column with data based on one of my incoming columns.

Comment: @ Warthog1, what is the purpose of adding a path , does it referring to  `Combined Book.csv`

Comment: How exactly do you run your script?

Comment: are you looking for something `

`final2.to_csv('C:\Users\ab\Desktop\conversion\Combined Book.csv', index=False)`

Comment: The path is the desired output folder, which is the folder that my .py and csv file are in. I want to add the path because right now the code doesn't output any CSV files, let alone into the desired folder. From research it looks like adding a path would remove that problem

Comment: @ w-m I am running it from the command line by calling convertbook.py and it executes without error

Comment: I would use `os.path.join(path,'Combined Book.csv')` Also if you executing it on windows you have to replace \  to \\ I think but os module should take care of it

Answer (score 3):

Join the path and the filename together and pass that to `pd.to_csv`:

```
import os
path = 'C:\Users\ab\Desktop\conversion'
output_file = os.path.join(path,'Combined Book.csv')

final2.to_csv(output_file, index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think below is what you are looking for , absolute path

```
import pandas as pd
.....
final2.to_csv('C:\Users\ab\Desktop\conversion\Combined Book.csv', index=False)
```

OR for an example:

```
path_to_file = "C:\Users\ab\Desktop\conversion\Combined Book.csv"
final2.to_csv(path_to_file, encoding="utf-8")
```

Answer (score 1):

Im pretty sure that you have mixed up the arguments, as shown [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html). The path should include the filename in it.

```
path = 'C:\Users\ab\Desktop\conversion\Combined_Book.csv'

final2.to_csv(path, index=False)
```

Otherwise you are trying to overwrite the whole folder 'conversions' and add a complicated value separator.

Answer (score 1):

Though late answer but would be useful for someone facing similar issues.  It is better to dynamically get the csv folder path instead of hardcoding it. We can do so using `os.getcwd()`. Later join the csv folder path with csv file name using  `os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'csvFileName')`

**Example:**

```
import os
path = os.getcwd()
export_path = os.path.join(path,'Combined Book.csv')
final2.to_csv(export_path, index=False, header=True)
```